# Why I still get number bigger than 1 when I normalize data in R?

Tags: r

I want to standard normalize my data in R (with mean zero and standard deviation 1.0 ), and I use `scale()` function. All of my numbers are bigger than zero. But when I normalize them, I still have numbers like ; 100,....
and more strange thing is that, when I plot the density, I have also density for negative values!!.

Here is subset of my data:

```
Tr[1:10,]
 [1] 1.287161e+01 1.300534e+00 1.140467e+00 7.958636e-01 4.886365e-01

data<-scale(Tr)
```

Would someone help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Consider posting a subset of your data and the code you are using, so people can reproduce your result.

Comment: What is your `mean` for the vector `Tr` and what is your `sd` for the vector `Tr` and what is the maximum value, `max`, in the vector `Tr`?

Answer (score 5):

Too long for a comment:

I don't see why you're surprised. The way you are using it, `scale(...)` substract the mean from each value and divides the result by the standard deviation. So any values less than the mean will scale to negative numbers, and any values more than 100 standard deviations from the mean will scale to > 100 ( or < -100). You probably have some outliers which are very large compared to mean/sd.

```
set.seed(1)
X <- rpois(1000,5)
Z <- scale(X)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
hist(X)
hist(Z)
```

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity I have been trying to create a data set in which one `X` has a `Z > 100` and so far I have not been able to.  I imagine it is possible.  I just have not been able to do it yet with all `X > 0`.

Comment: This will do it: `X <- c(rep(1,100000000), 10000000000000000000000000) ; Z <- ((X - mean(X)) / sd(X)) ; max(Z)`